# In TypeScript, Is it possible to read the properties defined in a class?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

For a defined class:

```
class TestClass {
            public testProp: string
            public testProp2: number
            public testProp3: boolean
            public testProp4: Date
            public testProp5: any
        }
```

Is it possible to enumerate all the defined properties in a way?

The idea is that I want to write a generic method to accept different types and iterate their properties:

```
function someMethod<T>() {
  // How to get the members of T?
}
```

If it's not possible directly, is it possible to have a way to achieve it similarly?

I tried `someMethod<TestClass>(new TestClass())`, and tried to use `Object.getOwnPerpertyNames(new TestClass())`, still get nothing.

Are there some helper built-in functions that can construct an object with default values that I can later enumerate the object's properties?

Comment: You *cannot* get the members of `T`. You can only get the properties of what was passed in. That's not necessarily going to coincide with `T`. Consider `someMethod<Animal>(new Cat())`

Comment: "*Are there some helper built-in functions that can construct an object with default values*" no. You seem to be missing that TS *does not exist at runtime*. There is no way to create something with default values, considering the concept of types only exists at runtime. `constructDefault(Cat)` can at most attempt to call the constructor. But if the TS constructor is `constructor(name: string, age: number)` at runtime, that's just two arguments with no type information to them. In JS `new Cat(true, ["hello", "world"])` is a valid call. Or rather not checked for validity.